# How to resolve this failure to integrate Guice into Dropwizard?

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

I tried to introduce Google Guice into my Dropwizard 2.0 project using **dropwizard-guicier** following this approach https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guicier but getting an error

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
Class org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessagingBinders$HeaderDelegateProviders does not implement the requested interface org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder
```

The same error is being thrown for `dropwizard-guice` https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice as well

Does anybody know what could be the root cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both aforementioned libraries are outdated and there's another one
**dropwizard-guicey** https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey that works in my case